# Unity 5 Head rotation in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am trying to make a realistic player controller in my game. the camera is not actually being moved. its parented to the rigged head. i want to move the rigged head so the camera moves with it. i am having trouble. i have tried many different things. they all come out weird. what i mean by that is it like curves to look down and its controls are flipped i have tried this code:

```
public float horizontalSpeed = 2.0F;
public float verticalSpeed = 2.0F;
void Update()
{
    float h = horizontalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    float v = verticalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
    transform.Rotate(h, v, 0);
}
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: 'Controls are flipped'... have you tried negating them like 'transform.Rotate(-h,-v,0)'?

Comment: it made it alot better! thanks.

Comment: No Problem, make sure to tweak each axis as per your needs